# orthographic projection matrix in Opengl-es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

```
float pfIdentity[] =
{
    -1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f
};
```

==================================================================================

```
    const char* pszVertShader = "\
    attribute highp vec4    myVertex;\
    uniform mediump mat4    myPMVMatrix;\
    invariant gl_Position;\
    void main(void)\
    {\
        gl_Position = myPMVMatrix * myVertex;\
}";
```

=====================================================================

```
for(int i = 0; i < 80000; ++i)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i32Location = glGetUniformLocation(uiProgramObject, "myPMVMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv( i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, pfIdentity);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,i);
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
}

return 0;
}
```

p.s : i am doing opengl-es in ubuntu 10.10 with kronos headers , its an emulator for opengl-es 2.0 in linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a projection at all. The Projection-Model-View matrix you're setting the `myPMVMatrix` uniform to is

```
float pfIdentity[] =
{
    -1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f
};

/* ... */

glUniformMatrix4fv( i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, pfIdentity);
```

BTW: The idea of uniforms is, that you don't set them at each primitive iteration.

Anyway, this is a identity matrix, and since it's the only transformation applied it will just pass through the vertices as they are to the fragment stage. The solution for your problem is applying a orthographic projection to it, i.e. multiply that matrix with a ortho projection matrix and use the result of that operation instead. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

Comment: HI i am not able to do this i dont know where to change the thing if you could tell me its easy for me to go far with this .

Comment: Look at the article about projection matrices I posted. Read it, understand it, use your new knowledge to build a orthographic projection matrix and supply it to the shader using glUniformMatrix.